# divide vector containing sequences with increment 1

Tags: matlab, sequence

I have a vector that contains several sequences with an increment of one, e.g.

```
in = [1:5 8:14 16:20 23:40]
```

For each of this sequences I would like to extract the start- and the endpoint of the sequence, i.e for above example I would get

```
out = [1 5; 8 14; 16 20; 23 40]
```

Of course, this can be done with a combination of for-loops and if-conditions, but that would not be very efficient and readable. Is there any more matlab-ish way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`diff`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to find where the runs stop and start and then use the resulting logical array (and a circularly shifted version of the logical array) to index into `in` to yield `out`

```
% Create a logical array that is TRUE at the beginning of each new run
starts = [true, diff(in) ~= 1];
%  1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

% Use that array to index into IN and shift it to index into IN again
out = [in(starts); in(circshift(starts, [0 -1]))].';

%     1     5
%     8    14
%    16    20
%    23    40
```

Comment: I had to change circshift(starts, -1) to circshift(starts, -1, 2) but now it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @snalx Is `in` not what you've shown in your question?

Comment: ´´in´´ is as shown in my question. I just copied it from this side into matlab and checked again. Frankly, I am also a bit confused why it needs dimension 2. I am using Matlab R2016a if that matters.

Comment: @snalx Ah ok. I was using 2016b. I've updated the syntax to use the format that will work on all versions.